# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function - React CommentBox Tutorial w/ ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React with ES6 and working on the basic example Facebook's tutorial walks you through.  I have successfully put everything together (I built a small JSON API using the [Lux Framework](https://github.com/postlight/lux) to serve to the application), but am running into one error:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function`

I know this is happening because my data is not being properly fetched in `loadCommentsFromServer()`, but can't seem to figure out why. Was hoping for a push in the right direction or an explanation as to why what I am doing is wrong.

I've provided a gist to the file because SO's markdown was being weird with the formatting when I included the whole file.

[gist - App.js](https://gist.github.com/gentle-noah/8b292322674ebc4dcc5337d435f64ecd)

[gist - JSON being passed](https://gist.github.com/gentle-noah/3e7f6e32c5687aae3b58fc8db3db12ea)

Comment: You might want to check that in`    success: (data) => {  this.setState({data: data});      },` that data is actually an array, and possibly call `JSON.parse` on it. Otherwise you have defined a default state that should not cause an error and it looks fine.

Comment: @erik-sn - got a little closer. Had to pass in the context of `this` into the ajax call using `context: this` and then `this.setState({ data: data.data })` becuase of JSON API's formatting. Hitting a new error now, but making progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was that I was not properly passing `context: this` into the AJAX call when fetching the data and that I need to step into the `data` attribute when setting the state with `this.setState({ data: data.data })`, becuase of the formatting of [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/).

An additional issue I found was that I was not passing the unique key with the `<Comment />` component when rendering.

[gist- Updated App.js](https://gist.github.com/gentle-noah/7e8a5a7653db689a35306cd15773f3a5)

Thank you to @erik-sn for leading me in the right direction.